# Найти в урле значение до слеша или конца значение

Tags: php, laravel

пытаюсь реализовать партнерскую ссылку вида `www.site.ru/en/p131213/products`

где p - приставка, цифры - это id пользователя

как в адресе найти этот id?

```
$uri = Request::path(); //получаем URI

      $segmentsURI = explode('/',$uri); //делим на части по разделителю "/"

      //Проверяем метку языка  - есть ли она среди доступных языков
      if (!empty($segmentsURI[0]) && in_array($segmentsURI[0], config('app')['locales'])) {
          foreach($segmentsURI as $value)
          {
            echo $value.'</br>';
          }
      }
```

Comment: отделить имя сайта от пути, написать регулярное выражение, соответствующие шаблону

Comment: проблема и заключается в регулярном выражении

Comment: `preg_match('/p(\d+)/', $uri, $matches); echo $matches[1]` не работает чтоль? у вас вообще запрос дойдет до этого кода, если локаль в ссылке будет не из списка, указанных в конфиге?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю лучше это делать через [роут](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-optional-parameters), наример так

```
Route::get("/{lang}/p{id}/products", function ($lang, $id) {
    if (in_array($lang, config('app')['locales'])) {
        ...
    }
});
```